# Usage of adverb in a sentence

Tags: grammar, adverbs

Is the usage of '**starting**' in this sentence correct?

> I'll begin my diet starting from next week.

Answer (score 1):

The usage of 'starting' would actually be redundant in that sentence, because starting and begin mean the same thing. Because they are synonymous, you can just use one of the two words instead. For example, could say, "I'll begin my diet next week", or "I'm starting my diet next week". There are also many other ways in which you could form your sentence using just one of the two.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is 'yes' the use of starting is perfectly ok.

It is true that you can omit 'starting from' entirely and the sentence means the same thing. But you didn't ask whether the sentence could be improved, you asked if it was grammatical. In normal spoken English the phrase you provided would be entirely accepted and unremarkable.